# Can't commit Xcode project with Git integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, git, github

I am trying to get GitHub working through Xcode and have been having quite a bit of trouble. When I click commit (under File/Source Control) I get this error message:

`The operation could not be performed because no valid working copies were found.` 
`Please verify that your files are under source control and try again.`

This happens whether I create a new project and click the "create with local git repository" box, or if I clone an existing project from github using the organizer's repository tab.

For some reason I am able to commit if I am in the organizer in the repositories tab, have my projects folder under the repository selected and click commit. This works, but from there I cannot push my update to github, since the push option is "grayed out" in the file menu.

Can anyone help me fix this? I would love to be able to push updates right through Xcode.

Comment: I spended a lot of time trying to make it work. if you'll find out something, plaease, let me know.

Comment: I use the terminal to do this, and tried to commit & push in XCode just now, it works either. Have you `init` & `add remote` correctly?

Comment: yes, i have done init and add remote

Answer (score 2):

If your project is in /Developer/.... move it elsewhere and reopen the project.  This may resolve your problem.

There seems to be a problem under Xcode 4.2 with projects in /Developer/... and git integration (you get the error *"The operation could not be performed because no valid working copies were found. Please verify that your files are under source control and try again"*)

Answer (score 1):

What's your Xcode version?
Above Xcode4.0, Git repos will create when Xcode project created.

If you want to add git to an existing project, you should initialize it first.
In project folder, typing:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "your comment"
```

More information details, click [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

Comment: Hey @Hes, he said 'I would love to be able to push updates right through Xcode.', not the terminal. :p